# What is the most resource efficient way to duplicate and then update multiple worksheets in a single spreadsheet using gspread with python?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am writing a python script that (along with some other things) duplicates a template spreadsheet on google sheets, duplicates a tab (worksheet) within that spreadsheet up to 25 times, and then updates those duplicated tabs with some information supplied by the script. The way I have accomplished this so far is by doing the following:

```
copied_spreadsheet = 'my new spreadsheet'

client.copy('(spreadsheet key))', title=copied_spreadsheet, copy_permissions=True)
copied_spreadsheet = client.open(spreadsheet_name)
```

To duplicate the template spreadsheet, then:

```
for idx, tab_name in enumerate(list_of_tabs_to_add):
     copied_spreadsheet.worksheet('template_tab').duplicate(insert_sheet_index=idx + 1, new_sheet_name=tab_name)
     supplied_information = ['stuff to add to the duplicated tab']
     copied_spreadsheet.worksheet(tab_name).update('A1:F3', supplied_information, value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')
```

This worked pretty well when I had to duplicate the template tab around 20 times, but when trying to do it 25 times, I've found myself occasionally running into a resource error where I exceed the quota for read requests per minute per user. The error looks something like this:

```
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 429, 'message': "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Read requests' and limit 'Read requests per minute per user' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer (etc...)
```

I've tried really hacky solutions like adding a `time.sleep()` command in between loops to try and act as a sort of buffer so I don't hit the quota as quickly, and that helps a bit, but the results can be a little hit and miss.

Apart from requesting a higher quota, is there anything I can do to make my code more efficient? I believe I am working with the default quotas, and I don't think what I'm doing is all that intensive, so my feeling is that I am just not coding this solution as efficiently as I could.

In my head I feel like the place I can get the most efficiency out of is the loop that duplicates and updates 25 times. Is there any way I can store the template worksheet into a variable, duplicate and modify that variable then upload the 25 copies with a single command instead of 25 times? I'm not very familiar with dataframes or the gspread_dataframes module, but does a potential solution exist with that library too, or is the way I'm currently going about it the best way to do it, necessitating a simple quota increase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to copy a sheet in Google Spreadsheet 25 times, and want to put the values of `supplied_information` to each copied sheet.

  - In this case, you want to reduce the process cost of the script.
- You want to achieve this using gspread of python.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

In this case, I would like to propose the following flow.

1. Retrieve the sheet ID of `template_tab` in the copied Google Spreadsheet.
2. Create 2 requests for "batchUpdate" and "values.batchUpdate" for Sheets API.
3. Request batchUpdate method using gspread.
4. Request values.batchUpdate method using requests module.

   - Because, in gspread, in the current stage, the values.batchUpdate method is not included. So, I used this using the requests module by retrieving the access token from the authorization script of gspread.

In this flow, 3 quotas of Sheets API are used. When this flow is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.
By the way, it seems that `client.copy()` returns a Spreadsheet instance.

#### Modified script:

Please set `'(spreadsheet key))'`, `list_of_tabs_to_add` and `supplied_information`.

```
client = gspread.authorize(credentials) # Please use your "credentials" here.

copied_spreadsheet = 'my new spreadsheet'
copied_spreadsheet = client.copy('(spreadsheet key))', title=copied_spreadsheet, copy_permissions=True)

list_of_tabs_to_add = [###] # <--- Please set value here.

# 1. Retrieve the sheet ID of `template_tab` in the copied Google Spreadsheet.
srcSheetId = copied_spreadsheet.worksheet('template_tab').id

# 2. Create 2 requests for "batchUpdate" and "values.batchUpdate" for Sheets API.
requests1 = []
requests2 = []
for idx, tab_name in enumerate(list_of_tabs_to_add):
    temp = idx + 1
    requests1.append({"duplicateSheet": {"sourceSheetId": srcSheetId, "insertSheetIndex": temp, "newSheetName": tab_name}})

    supplied_information = [###] # <--- Please set value here.

    requests2.append({"range": tab_name, "values": supplied_information})

# 3. Request batchUpdate method using gspread.
res1 = copied_spreadsheet.batch_update({"requests": requests1})

# 4. Request values.batchUpdate method using requests module.
res2 = requests.post(
    'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' + copied_spreadsheet.id + '/values:batchUpdate',
    headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + credentials.access_token, "Content-Type": "application/json"},
    data=json.dumps({"data": requests2, "valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED"}),
)
```

- In this script, `requests` and `json` libraries are required to be included.

#### References:

- [copy(file_id, title=None, copy_permissions=False, folder_id=None)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=copy#gspread.Client.copy)
- [batch_update(body)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=batch_update#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try this tonight then report back :)

Comment: I've just had a go at implementing your answer and I was able to duplicate the tabs, so res1 appears to work as intended, but the script fails when trying to execute res2. The error it's returning seems to revolve around authorisation because it returns the following:
headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + credentials.access_token, "Content-Type": "application/json"},
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
Could it have something to do with how I authorize the client in the first place?

Comment: Just adding here to say I was able to solve the auth problem. Instead of using credentials.access_token, I was able to use client.auth.token instead and the code worked! Thank you again for your help! While it all works as intended the only thing I'm unclear on is how the script knows to put 'supplied_information' in 'A1:F3' in each tab. Is it just defaulting to 'A1' because that's the first cell in the tab? What would I have to do if I wanted that information somewhere else, say 'B2:E10' for example?

Comment: @user3153443  Thank you for replying. I apologize for my late response. At the method of "spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate", when the sheet name is used as the range, the upper left cell is always "A1". When I saw your script, the upper left cell is "A1". So I used it. For example, when you want to change the upper left cell to `B2:E10`, it is required to set the cell as a1Notation like `'sheetName'!B2`. By this, the upper left cell becomes `B2`. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.